# When installing, the user setup part skips after a couple seconds and goes into installation and fails

Tags: system-installation

I’m using a late 2013 MacBook Pro, I don't know what to do, and the console is blank

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what you're actually trying to install? (ie. Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? etc) nor what release of that product?  (some also have multiple ISO choices that use different installers; eg. there are two choices for Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 and we don't know which product/release you tried; not which ISO/installer you're attempting to use), so how are we to help?  You also haven't mentioned if you verified the ISO prior to download? or write of ISO to install media? or if  media issues were detected (ie. did you explore logs? or look for clues?)